# Any internal contention when using PostgreSQL pg_try_advisory_lock

Tags: postgresql

I am using the PostreSQL `pg_try_advisory_lock` function to coordinate a cluster of micro-services, sharing the same database, to ensure that only one instance performs an ad hoc task.

Does this function contend with any internal locks PostresSQL may be using. I am concerned that using a database wide locking mechanism such as this may impact the system resources used within the database engine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PostgreSQL does not use advisory locks internally, so there is no danger of blocking anything in the system by using them.